# Editing then concatenating values of several columns into a single one (pandas, python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm looking for a way to use pandas and python to combine several columns in an excel sheet with known column names into a new, single one, keeping all the important information as in the example below:

input:

```
ID,tp_c,tp_b,tp_p  
0,transportation - cars,transportation - boats,transportation - planes
1,checked,-,-
2,-,checked,-
3,checked,checked,-
4,-,checked,checked
5,checked,checked,checked
```

desired output:

```
ID,tp_all  
0,transportation  
1,cars  
2,boats  
3,cars+boats  
4,boats+planes  
5,cars+boats+planes
```

The row with ID of 0 contans a description of the contents of the column.  Ideally the code would parse the description in the second row, look after the '-' and concatenate those values in the new "tp_all" column.

Comment: As BrenBarn has stated if the resultant values are in the column headers then it is easier to parse rather than in the first row

Comment: Sorry I guess I simplified my example way too much.  There are over 400 other columns, so I would be ok with specifying the 5 or so columns I want to combine and what values to concatanate, if parsing the second row would add too much complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK a more dynamic method:

```
In [63]:
# get a list of the columns
col_list = list(df.columns)
# remove 'ID' column
col_list.remove('ID')
# create a dict as a lookup
col_dict = dict(zip(col_list, [df.iloc[0][col].split(' - ')[1] for col in col_list]))
col_dict
Out[63]:
{'tp_b': 'boats', 'tp_c': 'cars', 'tp_p': 'planes'}
In [64]:
# define a func that tests the value and uses the dict to create our string
def func(x):
    temp = ''
    for col in col_list:
        if x[col] == 'checked':
            if len(temp) == 0:
                temp = col_dict[col]
            else:
                temp = temp + '+' + col_dict[col]
    return temp
df['combined'] = df[1:].apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
df
Out[64]:
   ID                   tp_c                    tp_b                     tp_p  \
0   0  transportation - cars  transportation - boats  transportation - planes   
1   1                checked                     NaN                      NaN   
2   2                    NaN                 checked                      NaN   
3   3                checked                 checked                      NaN   
4   4                    NaN                 checked                  checked   
5   5                checked                 checked                  checked   

            combined  
0                NaN  
1               cars  
2              boats  
3         cars+boats  
4       boats+planes  
5  cars+boats+planes  

[6 rows x 5 columns]
In [65]:

df = df.ix[1:,['ID', 'combined']]
df
Out[65]:
   ID           combined
1   1               cars
2   2              boats
3   3         cars+boats
4   4       boats+planes
5   5  cars+boats+planes

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I edited my question, any way to accomplish the way I asked now?  Also,  I'd rather drop the columns that I no longer need than select the ones I do need, since my real data has 400+ columns.

Comment: This does exactly what I need.  Thanks & I apologize for the last minute edits.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite interesting as it's a reverse `get_dummies`...

I think I would manually munge the column names so that you have a boolean DataFrame:

```
In [11]: df1  # df == 'checked'
Out[11]:
    cars  boats planes
0
1   True  False  False
2  False   True  False
3   True   True  False
4  False   True   True
5   True   True   True
```

Now you can use an apply with zip:

```
In [12]: df1.apply(lambda row: '+'.join([col for col, b in zip(df1.columns, row) if b]),
                   axis=1)
Out[12]:
0
1                 cars
2                boats
3           cars+boats
4         boats+planes
5    cars+boats+planes
dtype: object
```

Now you just have to tweak the headers, to get the desired csv.

*Would be nice if there were a less manual way / faster to do reverse `get_dummies`...*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm not familiar with get_dummies.  I'll read up on it, but it doesn't seem necessary to change values to boolean values.

Comment: It's not necessary but I would argue easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
newCol = pandas.Series('',index=d.index)
for col in d.ix[:, 1:]:
    name = '+' + col.split('-')[1].strip()
    newCol[d[col]=='checked'] += name
newCol = newCol.str.strip('+')
```

Then:

```
>>> newCol
0                 cars
1                boats
2           cars+boats
3         boats+planes
4    cars+boats+planes
dtype: object
```

You can create a new DataFrame with this column or do what you like with it.

Edit: I see that you have edited your question so that the names of the modes of transportation are now in row 0 instead of in the column headers.  It is easier if they're in the column headers (as my answer assumes), and your new column headers don't seem to contain any additional useful information, so you should probably start by just setting the column names to the info from row 0, and deleting row 0.

Comment: Hi yes this would work for my the data in the simplified example but my real data has 400+ columns, and the column headers are not always clear in what the contain, so deleting an entire row (i.e. the description row) is not an option.  Is there a way to modify your answer for my edited question?

Comment: @ferrios25: Not sure what you mean by "the column headers are not always clear in what they contain".  Can you not just *replace* the column headers with row 0?  It's generally awkward to have individual rows with special meaning; you want all rows to have the same format.

Comment: @BrenDarn: I see what you mean, I can temporarily try setting my current row 0 to be column headers.  What I meant was that "t_p", "t_c", "t_b" are not always clear descriptions in what the column contains, but I need to keep them around because they are they keys in some database that I might need in order to fill in missing values in the future.  I also need to keep the description row so I know what values I'm working with as I combine and delete columns in my attempt to clean up this data.

Comment: @ferrios25: I'd suggest that you keep that information outside the DataFrame (e.g., a separate dict mapping your database keys to the descriptions).