# Merge dummies value columns to one column (pd.get_dummies reversed)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this :

```
id     Apple   Apricot   Banana    Climentine   Orange    Pear    Pineapple
01       1        1         0          0          0         0         0    
02       0        0         1          1          1         1         0 
03       0        0         0          0          1         0         1
```

How can I generate a new DataFrame like this?

```
id     fruits
01     Apple, Apricot
02     Banana, Clementine, Orange, Pear
03     Orange, Pineapple
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. If i have second dataframe, is it possible to get the first one?

Comment: Thanks. I update my questions.

Comment: Thanks for your tips and i'll do it. I'm a newbie on stackoverflow and i'm glad to have so much kind help.

Comment: You are welcome! Nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), filter `1` and last join values per groups with `,`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['01','02','03'],
    'Apple': [1,0,0],
    'Apricot': [1,0,0],
    'Banana': [0,1,0],
    'Climentine': [0,1,0],
    'Orange': [0,1,1],
    'Pear': [0,1,0],
    'Pineapple': [0,0,1]
})

df = (df.melt('id', var_name='fruits').query('value == 1')
       .groupby('id')['fruits']
       .apply(', '.join)
       .reset_index())

print (df)

#   id                            fruits
#0   1                    Apple, Apricot
#1   2  Banana, Climentine, Orange, Pear
#2   3                 Orange, Pineapple
```

For better performance use `dot` for matrix multiplication:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ').reset_index(name='fruit')
print (df)
   id                             fruit
0  01                    Apple, Apricot
1  02  Banana, Climentine, Orange, Pear
2  03                 Orange, Pineapple
```

Answer (score 2):

OK I made some searches here on SO and found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045425/7386332

The equivalent here would simply be as `0` evaluates to `False` inside the comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['01','02','03'],
    'Apple': [1,0,0],
    'Apricot': [1,0,0],
    'Banana': [0,1,0],
    'Climentine': [0,1,0],
    'Orange': [0,1,1],
    'Pear': [0,1,0],
    'Pineapple': [0,0,1]
})


df = (df.set_index('id')
       .apply(lambda row: ', '.join([col for col, b in zip(df.columns, row) if b]), 
              axis=1)
       .reset_index())
```

#### Time comparison

Small set (the above)

```
1.37 ms ± 4.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) # list comprehensio
1.41 ms ± 2.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) # df.dot
3.28 ms ± 81.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) # df.melt
```

Using (`df = pd.concat([df]*1000)`) to simulate larger set:

```
36.9 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) # df.dot
39.8 ms ± 369 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) # df.melt
84.5 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) # list comprehension
```

Comment: Can you add new solution to timings?

Comment: @jezrael ofc second.

Comment: @jezrael The dot version is the "best". But I think the melt version is the easiest to understand

Comment: @jezrael Maybe... but it is really smart :) Sorry but can only upvote once.